# VBA Passing variable to a PageSetUp Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, variables, arguments

I have a couple of different sheets I need to print and the PageSetup properties are pretty much the same except for a RightFooter or LeftHeader that changes based on each sheet.

I'm trying to built a Function that I can change these properties without repeating 90% of the sub for each sheet I need to print.

I'm not sure if the variables should be in the function or in the sub1().

Any help is appreciated.

Nick

```
Function PgSetUp(LH As String, Optional LF As String, Optional RF As String, Optional RH)

Dim UN As String, CurrTime As Date

UN = Environ("UserName")
CurrTime = Format(Now, "dd mmm yyyy")

LH = "Test_11111"
LF = CurrTime
RF = "Printed by XXXX: "

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = LH & CurrTime
        .LeftFooter = LF
        .RightFooter = RF & UN
    End With
    
End Function

'------------------------------------------------------------

Sub Test1()

   PgSetUp (LH = "Test_222222", RF= " Printet by YYYYY: ") ' Here it expects an "=" somehow

   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PrintPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: That call to PgSetUp should look like
PgSetUp (LH:="Test_222222", RF:= " Printet by YYYYY: ")
And why use a Function if you are not trying to return a value?

Comment: Oh thanks Chill60,  I tried it with ":=" and it is working. I was wrong about using a Function. I just tried it with Call PgSetUp () and it is working On a side note the variables in the Function apparently were not needed .  Thank you